# Allow tweet embed

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editor, twitter

<strike>Would it be nice</strike> I believe that embedding a Tweet in a question/answer with [Embedded Tweets feature](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) would be a good way to make it clear you're quoting a tweet.

As I saw some posts today that used block quote to do it and thought it would be better if those quotes used Embedded Tweets format style.

The embedding could be achieve with the following code:

```
[tweet https://twitter.com/twitterapi/status/133640144317198338]
```

Comment: why would this be a good idea exactly?

Comment: So let me understand - you want to place a link, to a tweet, that will get deleted in about 90 days because twitter doesn't maintain history forever? You can guarantee link-rot manually if you want, but I don't support adding a button to make it even easier.

Comment: If you are going to propose something that "would be nice", please also explain why this would be so. What would the benefit be? What kind of positive effect will this have on the (quality of this) Q&A?

Comment: FYI: [Voting is different on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @AaronBertrand the tweet is not linked, it's hardcopied. Also, the Tweet from the page I sent is still online if you access this URL https://twitter.com/twitterapi/statuses/133640144317198338?tw_i=133640144317198338&tw_e=details&tw_p=tweetembed

Comment: @AaronBertrand maybe the tweet could be created the same way it sugests in the article for plataform that support the tweet embeding: `[tweet https://twitter.com/twitterapi/status/133640144317198338]`. It doen't necessarily need a button.

Comment: Even if that tweet is still alive, how do you know it will ever be? And my objection isn't about a button, it's about making this process easier in general. How many times are you referencing a tweet in a question or answer? Really?

Comment: @Lix and Bart, thanks for the tip. Edited the answer to try explaining my point.

Comment: I would argue that for some discussions (such as politics) tweets are in themselves evidence that a specific verified person said something. This may be useless for discussions about programming, but I believe is meaningful for recent and current history related topics.

Answer (score 15):

I think this would be bad for two reasons:

1. Some companies block Twitter, so any information embedded in a Tweet would be inaccessible to many users for a significant portion of the time.
2. Any information in a Tweet can be easily copied into a question or answer with a link for reference.

Comment: Copy and paste **140 CHARACTERS!** What do you people have, supercomputers????!!!?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill *Up to* 140 characters.  Many tweets are shorter, and can be copy/pasted on even common desktop hardware.

Comment: What is this "Copy and paste" you're speaking of?

Comment: @BilltheLizard you have a good point on companies policy there. It indeed need to load a script from Twitter plataform.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill it's naive to think the point is about saving a copy and paste operation. It's for the sake of formatting only. Just like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> can be easily written as `ctrl+c`.

Comment: I believe the limitation on policies @BilltheLizard pointed out is really complicated.